# Can I read an atomic variable without atomic_load?

Tags: c, multithreading, c11

I have a single-writer, multiple-reader situation. There's a counter that one thread is writing to, and any thread may read this counter. Since the single writing thread doesn't have to worry about contending with other threads for data access, is the following code safe?

```
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdint.h>

_Atomic uint32_t counter;

// Only 1 thread calls this function. No other thread is allowed to.
uint32_t increment_counter() {
    atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&counter, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
    return counter;  // This is the line in question.
}

// Any thread may call this function.
uint32_t load_counter() {
    return atomic_load_explicit(&counter, memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

The writer thread just reads the `counter` directly without calling any `atomic_load*` function. This should be safe (since it's safe for multiple threads to read a value), but I don't know if declaring a variable `_Atomic` restricts you from using that variable directly, or if you're required to always read it using one of the `atomic_load*` functions.

Comment: I'd venture that the strict answer is "No, it's not safe" but I don't have the time to actually research it right now.  Trying to directly read an otherwise atomic variable that can be updated assumes that the update itself is atomic.  But if the update of the variable were atomic, there'd be no need to explicitly make it atomic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, all operations that you do on `_Atomic` objects are guaranteed to be effected as if you would issue the corresponding call with sequential consistency. And in your particular case an evaluation is equivalent to `atomic_load`.

But the algorithm as used there is wrong, because by doing an `atomic_fetch_add` and an evaluation the value that is returned may already be change by another thread. Correct would be

```
uint32_t ret = atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&counter, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
return ret+1;
```

This looks a bit suboptimal because the addition is done twice, but a good optimizer will sort this out.

Comment: Note that I said this was a single-writer situation. There isn't any risk of another thread modifying `counter`, because there's only one thread that may do that in my code. Also, do you have a reference to the standard that says/implies "all operations that you do on `_Atomic` objects are guaranteed to be effected as if you would issue the corresponding call with sequential consistency"? I tried reading from the standard but couldn't find anywhere that mentioned being able to use an `_Atomic` variable directly without one of the corresponding atomic functions.

Comment: It is a bit spreadout. Basically all the arithmetic operations have an extra phrase that states what happens if the object in atomic qualified.

Comment: Ah, I think I may have found the relevant quote. "Loads and stores of objects with atomic types are done with `memory_order_seq_cst` semantics." (section 6.2.6.1 paragraph 9) Looking at the standard, you're right; it's kinda spread out (e.g. post-increment/decrement talks about atomics in 6.5.2.4/2). Thanks for clarifying that!

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite the function, this question goes away:

```
uint32_t increment_counter() {
    return 1 + atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&counter, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's a way to work around this problem, and if this were my real code it would be a good idea. But the code I posted was just the simplest MVCE I could write that still illustrated the actual question. In my real code the two lines in the `increment_counter` function are actually split up into two different functions (though still with the same constraint of only being used by a single thread).